# Could not file location while importing dataset to Excel in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

I have a dataset and I want to import it into Excel where a number of data table will be equal to Excel sheets please tell me what I am done wrong.

My code

```
private void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds)
{
    //Creae an Excel application instance
    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

    //Create an Excel workbook instance and open it from the predefined location*emphasized text*
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\SSRS\\TFSWorkitem.xlsx");


    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
    {
        //Add a new worksheet to workbook with the Datatable name
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
        excelWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;

        for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    excelWorkBook.Save();
    excelWorkBook.Close();
    excelApp.Quit();
}
```

Comment: what's the error ? the code seems to be correct

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Sorry, we couldn't find C:\SSRS\TFSWorkitem.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?'

Answer (score 0):

a workbook must exist in a directory in order to use open;

i suggest you use this code :

```
    private void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds)
    {
        //Creae an Excel application instance
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

       Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(); 
        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            //Add a new worksheet to workbook with the Datatable name
            Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
            excelWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;

            for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
 //save the Excel workbook
        excelWorkBook.Saveas("C:\\SSRS\\TFSWorkitem.xlsx", 
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
        excelWorkBook.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: name excelworkbook does not exist in current context. ERROR

Comment: add this Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.add(); before the loop